# Problems with CssMenuMaker

Tags: html, css, menu

I am having a problem with a online menu maker I found called CssMenuMaker.com

The Instructions are pretty straight forward

```
     Installation Instructions
        Upload the menu_assets folder to the root directory of your website. This is usually where your 
    index.html file is.
        Copy and paste the code below somewhere between the <head></head> tags.
<link href="/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        Copy and paste the html below where ever you want your menu to show up.
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I do that, yet the menu only shows up as text, like it did not see the style.css

The style.css contains

```
    #cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #eeeeee;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #d9d9d9 url(images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(100%, #bfbfbf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9d9d9', endColorstr='#bfbfbf', GradientType=0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(100%, #bfbfbf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9d9d9', endColorstr='#bfbfbf', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  background: #bfbfbf url(images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #e5e5e5), color-stop(51%, #d7d7d7), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 35px;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff url(images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(50%, #bfbfbf), color-stop(51%, #b0b0b0), color-stop(100%, #c7c7c7));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: -1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  *width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

However when I copy and paste BOTH the style.css code and the code for the table into the actual index.html file, the table appears with the .css formatting.

This leads me to believe the

```
<link href="/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Is not working correctly, any ideas?

Here is the code that doesnt work on my website

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">


    <head>
    <link href="/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <title> Main website</title
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='minecrft2.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: red; font-family: Arial, salmonblack;"> Welcome To The main Minecrft Website!</h1>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Here is the code that works on my website

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">


    <head>
    <link href="/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <title> Main website</title
    </head>
    <body>

<style type="text/css">#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #eeeeee;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #d9d9d9 url(menu_assets/images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(100%, #bfbfbf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9d9d9', endColorstr='#bfbfbf', GradientType=0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(100%, #bfbfbf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9d9d9', endColorstr='#bfbfbf', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  background: #bfbfbf url(menu_assets/images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #e5e5e5), color-stop(51%, #d7d7d7), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 35px;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff url(menu_assets/images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(50%, #bfbfbf), color-stop(51%, #b0b0b0), color-stop(100%, #c7c7c7));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: -1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  *width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both; margin: 0 0 30px 0;">&nbsp;</div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: red; font-family: Arial, salmonblack;"> Welcome To The main Minecrft Website!</h1>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Thanks so much!
Sorry for the long question

Update:
After the answer below, I tried and still failed, I uploaded a picture to help show the problem. 
[image: As you can see the stlyes.css is in the menu_assest directory, the href =" is the first line]
The url is 
http://www.captainminecraftist.com/minecrft2.html#

So you can see what is showing up. Thanks!

Comment: [ssce](http://sscce.org/) please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to just update the path to the css file as you suggest. 
Where is this css file located in regard to the html document? if it is in the same directory then use

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

if it is in a subfolder use

```
<link href="subfolder/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tZB3f/

**UPDATE:**

Based on the image you've provided, the correct path from the index.html file would be:

```
<link href="menu_assets/images/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and in minecraft2.html it would be:

```
<link href="images/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I uploaded a photo to show the problem, Its under the subfolder directory but still not showing up correctly :/